# Magento add product programatically with custom option is required field

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

I try to add simple product programmatically  it's working fine but i want to add product with custom option how i achieve this?

```
public function addtocartAction(){
      /* Get Product id From Form Post */
        $product_id = $this->getRequest()->getPost('productids');
      /* Get Product id From Form Post */

      /* Add Product in to Cart */
        $product=new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
        $product->load($product_id); // Product Id
        $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        $quote->addProduct($product); // quantity is 1
        $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
        $cart->init(); // tried commenting this too!
        $cart->save();
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
        $quote->collectTotals()->save();
        $this->_redirectReferer();
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your product has been Added successfully...'); 
      /* Add Product in to Cart */
    }
```

**Note** I have multiple Custom option i need to get **Is Required = Yes** option in list.phtml and add it How I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
public function checkoutAction()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        try
        {
            if($data)
            {
                        $productId=$data['id'];
                        $qty=$data['qty'];
                        $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
                        $cart->init();
                        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($data['id']);
                        $formKey = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();
                        $product->setSkipCheckRequiredOption(true);
                        Mage::app()->cleanCache();
                        $option=array();

                        foreach ($product ->getOptions() as $value) 
                        {
                            $values = $value->getValues();
                            switch(trim($value->getData('title')))
                            {
                                case 'color':
                                        $colorMainID=$value->getData('option_id');
                                        break;
                                case 'jug':
                                        $jugMainID=$value->getData('option_id');
                                        break;
                                case 'shield cover':
                                        $shieldMainID=$value->getData('option_id');
                                        break;
                            }
                        }


                        if($data['shieldid']!='')
                        {
                            $option[$shieldMainID]=$data['shieldid'];
                        }
                        if($data['colorid']!='')
                        {
                            $option[$colorMainID]=$data['colorid'];
                        }
                        if($data['jugid']!='')
                        {
                            $option[$jugMainID]=$data['jugid'];
                        }

                        if($product->getSku()!='')
                            {

                                        $paramater = array(
                                                        'product' => $productId,
                                                        'qty' => $qty,
                                                        'form_key' => $formKey,
                                                         'options' => $option
                                                    );       
                                $request = new Varien_Object();
                                $request->setData($paramater);
                                $cart->addProduct($product, $request);
                                $cart->save();
                        }
                    $cart->save();
                    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true); 
            }
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            $session->addError($e->getMessage());   
        }
    }
```

i use this code to add product with custom option
you must specify custom option id to add with custom option
color,jug,shiled are the custom main option id
[image]

Comment: Actually custom option they create manually lot of we can't restrict Tilltle value

Comment: if you want to add product programatically with custom option . you must specify all required custom option

Comment: in my case only 3 custom option are there so i add it with given code.,  all work fine

Comment: Yes but i don't want to featch bacsed on title name

Comment: use id instead of title

Comment: Sorry not getting can you please give me phtml code

Comment: i give my code in my answer so use that code

Comment: i am asking phtml front end code

Comment: it will use any phtml or php file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48994/discussion-between-jigs-parmar-and-kothari).